# Why is my Python speechRecognition.listen not stopping to record

Tags: python, pyaudio

Hi im currently looking for the easiest possible python voice assistant. I watched some to tutorials and managed it to write this code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

speech_engine = sr.Recognizer()


def from_mic():
    with sr.Microphone() as micro:
        print("Recording...")
        audio = speech_engine.listen(micro)
        print("Recognizing...")
        text = speech_engine.recognize_google(audio, language="de-DE")
        return text

print(from_mic())
```

I am sure that listen() normally should stop when I stop speaking, but my programm just runs and says Recording... it does not try to figure out what has been said. It can also be because of my bad headset which makes white noise but i dont think so. But i dont find any mistake in the code

Comment: it can be noise in microphone.

Comment: try `speech_engine.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)` before `speech_engine.listen(micro)`

Comment: in documentation you have [The recognizer tries to recognize speech even when I'm not speaking, or after I'm done speaking.](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition#the-recognizer-tries-to-recognize-speech-even-when-im-not-speaking-or-after-im-done-speaking)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
speech_engine.adjust_for_ambient_noise(micro)
```

before listening.

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/66070703/2) to the question [SOLVED: Why is my Python speechRecognition.listen not stopping to record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66070703/solved-why-is-my-python-speechrecognition-listen-not-stopping-to-record) by the OP [Devolper12345](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12959435/devolper12345) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>